# Issues with shutil copy2 function

Tags: python, shutil

I have been using the `copy2` function to copy files and it has been working fine on the Linux system with both the source and destination directories in Linux. Recently I tried to use the Windows File share as the backend and was trying to copy files to my linux system. The code and the error displayed is as follows:

```
for afile in self.task_files:
    copy2(os.path.join(self.uploads_directory, afile), self.files_directory)
    count += 1`
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                
File "/opt/backend/worker.py", line 43, in <module>                                                                                                                                               
task.initialize()                                                                                                                                                                             
File "/opt/backend/services/task.py", line 58, in initialize                                                                                                                                      
copy2(os.path.join(self.uploads_directory, afile), self.files_directory)                                                                                                                      
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 252, in copy2                                                                                                                                           
copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)                                                                                                                                           
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 219, in copystat                                                                                                                                        
_copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)                                                                                                                                                  
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 151, in _copyxattr                                                                                                                                      
names = os.listxattr(src, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)                                                                                                                                  
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/data/uas/uploads/DJI_0049_vnbh0.JPG'
```

Is the `copy2` function unable to transfer the files because of the OS or is it something else? Also is there any other function in python which can be used to copy files along with its metadata?

Comment: Hi [sohank17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13047678/sohank17)! Can you please be specific about your version of python and the version of shutil you are using? Also, I would advice that you include your terminal output as text in the question - links will break over time. And, welcome!

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Hi @AndreasLorenzen I am using python 3.5 and as for shutil I guess its the same as the python version. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Hi @AMC. I am sorry for the formatting as I am new to posting on stack overflow. Thank you for the information on images!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At the very least you could share the contents of the relevant variables.

Comment: Possible related with question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616058/shutil-copystat-fails-inside-docker-on-azure and issue https://web.archive.org/web/20191214185453/https://bugs.python.org/issue24564

Comment: What about using *copy* or *copyfile* instead of *copy2*?

Comment: I was able to successfully run the command on a file from a windows share (mounted via *cifs-utils* (*mount.cifs*)).